# imagemagick -highlight-color method

Tags: imagemagick, qtp

I am using imagemagick command:

```
compare imgcopy.tif imgorig.tif -compose src -highlight-color blue imgdif.tif
```

in qtp like this:

```
set img = CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1")
img.Compare Path & img1.tif, path & img2.tif ,"-compose src -highlight-color blue & path & imgdif.tif
```

and it doesn't work...

If I use it without

```
-compose src -highlight-color
```

the command works just fine

```
 set img = CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1")
    img.Compare Path & img1.tif, path & img2.tif ,path & imgdif.tif
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? Also there seems to be an un-balanced quote `"-compose` is this in your real code too?